# How to have a pop-up text like questions or text-field on a touch-point

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm currently creating a game using react-three-fiber and I want to implement a touch-point that has pop-up questions or text that will be answered by the player. Already done with the touchpoints but Im stuck creating a pop-up that corresponds to the touchpoints.

Comment: Try using React ```Modals```

Comment: tried it but I couldnt find a way how to implement it to r3f.

Comment: Do you look for those to be embedded in the scene? Must they be interactive or just readable? I would recommend THREE.CSS2DObject, that’s what I use for tooltips and labels.

Comment: yes it must be embedded on the scene and must be interactive. do you have any examples if I may ask? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Only based on your description and comments (embedded and interactive), two options could fit into your needs.
First option would be using [`Annotations`](https://manu.ninja/webgl-three-js-annotations/) where the annotation content is basically pure HTML, but you would need to explore in a PoC the interactivity adding a button with an event.
[image]

Second option could be [`CSS2DObject`](https://jsfiddle.net/p83uog9w/7/), in this case the HTML must be built in runtime and sent to the `CSS2DObject` constructor through [`CSS2DRenderer`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#examples/en/renderers/CSS2DRenderer). The only sample I have on hand is for mapbox, where I use them to create tooltips in altitude. It's normally used for labeling, not interactive, but as it receives HTML I'm quite sure there must be a way to make possible to create a button on it.
[image]

Here you have a full example of [`CSS2DRenderer` and `CSS2DObject`](https://threejs.org/examples/?q=css2d#css2d_label)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It helped me understand the renderers from three.js. Its a little bit complicated though. What I am really trying to implement is the same like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-pasteur-m77l2vp00x?from-embed=&file=/index.js

Comment: Your sample is using `Alert` class from react-bootstrap, which is definitely a great solution (and simpler, as you said)

Answer (score 0):

you can use html overlays in react-three-fiber declaratively: https://codesandbox.io/s/r3f-suspense-zu2wo you would normally use css2drenderer etc, but i would suggest you skip it and go directly for the `<Html />` component in [drei](https://github.com/react-spring/drei). inside it you can use any component lib for pop-ups or whatever you want.